# gvim key mappings under alt results in special characters

Tags: debian, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, kde, gvim

For some reason `gVim` (debian stretch + kde) started to map `Alt`+`i` to "é" and `Alt` + other characters are also tied to some special letters e.g. `Atl`+`o`="ï" and `Alt`+`p`="ð". The problem is that this key mappings are nowhere set in gvim. Further, `gVim` is the application under `KDE` in which this happens (tried in `Vim`, `Firefox`, `Kate`, `KWrite`, terminal). So, while in some oses (Windows) this seems to be a standard mapping (however based on the current keyboard selection e.g. `Atl`+`V` = "@" in Czech keyboard but not US keyboard), I do not seem to see the same case in Debian+KDE.

The question, where do these mappings come from?

How to get rid of those so that the standard mappings in vim latex start to work again (`Alt`+`I` = new item in `itemize`).

Comment: I can reproduce this here (also stretch and KDE), so it's no broken setting on your system. Sorry, I can't answer the question. Maybe try on https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have a look at the answer of https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19098/latex-suite-alt-i-mapping

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!